# How do I simply adjust the color temperature In Photoshop Elements?

Tags: white-balance, photoshop-elements

How do I simply adjust the temperature of an image in Photoshop Elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a walkthrough of the camera raw white balance feature on the [adobe web site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshopelements/using/WS287f927bd30d4b1f5548d97812e28a69a90-7ff3.html).

Comment: Does this require the image to be in RAW?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Color Cast functionality (Enhance -> Color -> Color Cast). There's no temperature range you can click on, so it's a matter of trial and error using the Eyedropper tool over the photo. This approach works also if you are working with JPEG files.